# What are the ways to obtain higher version of a software?

Tags: hacker-experience

I've been lucky enough to find someone with a cracker v6.1, but I'm still stuck with my old hasher v2.5... I'm done with the puzzles (except the 2048 one) and for the moment pretty stuck at upgrading my hardware and waiting for more missions.

Is there another way I can get/find higher version of my softwares?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to upgrade your software:

**The first is to take someone else's software.** They worked so hard to get it, why wouldn't you take a copy? Just make sure to erase the logs so he can't trace your IP back. It's as simple as that.

**The second way is to upgrade it yourself!** To do that, you only need to purchase a license for your software and then do research on it. It doesn't matter if you take the software of someone else or not, you should always be able to do research on it in the university to upgrade its level.

So you could go find that v6.1 cracker and copy it then do research on it. You will upgrade it each time you do a research on it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could simply do the Puzzles. Even if you can't complete them, google the answer, as someone *else* did it already. The only annoying thing is that you have to constantly erase your IP to not get tracked. I went AFK for a short time and got 2 viruses, and they WEREN'T hidden. Sad thing is that I simply cannot get rid of em cuz my Anti-Virus simply isn't a good enough type. So, puzzle route it is.